# Questions about derivation of Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

### I am learning some statistics on my own after my bachelor's degree. I am trying to understand the properties of the test statistics for the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test (for paired data).

[image]

```
# Below is the example dataset on the book (I re-created in R)
        yA = c(23.5, 12, 21, 22,19.124,21.5,22.125,20.375,18.25,21.625,23.250,21,22.125,23,12)
        yB = c(17.375,20.375,20,20,18.375,18.625,18.625,15.25,16.5,18,16.25,18,12.75,15.5,18)
        cats = c(rep("I",3), rep("II",3),rep("III",5),rep("IV",4))
        paired_data = cbind(cats,yA,yB,round(yA-yB,4))
        paired_data = as.data.frame(paired_data)
        colnames(paired_data) = c("Pot","Crossed","Self-Fertilized","Difference")
        paired_data[c("Crossed","Self-Fertilized","Difference")] <- sapply(paired_data[c("Crossed","Self-Fertilized","Difference")],as.numeric)
        print(paired_data)
```

Comment: See [BBR](https://hbiostat.org/bbr) for a simple alternate formula that handles ties automatically.  But please state the question you have

Comment: Thank you so much for your link. I find it very helpful! My questions are as follows: a) what exactly is R1 as defined in Step 4 in the picture? Where did the (n+1)/2 term come from? b) Shouldn't Var(W) be n^2*(n+1)*(n+2)/6?

Comment: It says in the image you posted, "$R_1$ is the signed rank of the first difference". That is, you take the pairs of data values $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, ... . Now take pair-differences $d_1=y_1-x_1$ etc. You rank their absolute values $|d_i|$. You attach the signs of the $d$'s back to the corresponding rank you just calculated. You now have a list of ranks with attached signs. The first one in the list of those values is $R_1$. $R_1$ has a 50-50 chance of having either sign under the null, and the average rank from $1$ to $n$ is $(n+1)/2$. The variance formula is correct.